# Rate-limit Apache with Blacklist and Whitelist

Tags: http, apache-http-server

I spent several hours trying to configure iptables/ufw to do this for HTTP requests handled by Apache2:

White list a set of IP ranges (search engine bots)
Add IPs to a 24 hour block list after X requests in Y seconds (ideally I'd like to set three rules like this)

But it seemed to me that it is not possible to do that with iptables as it will only ban IPs for a short period of time.

Does anyone know if it is possible to do what I have outlined can be achieved with mod_security? Or recommend something that may do this? Any code snippets that do something similar would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of tweaks were required over the above. This works:

```
sudo ipset -N whitelist nethash
sudo ipset --add whitelist 68.180.228.175
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set whitelist src -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -N BLOCK24
sudo iptables -A BLOCK24 -m recent --name blocked --set
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 20 --hitcount 20 -j BLOCK24
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name blocked --rcheck --seconds 86400 -j BLOCK24
sudo iptables -A BLOCK24 -j LOG --log-prefix='[NETFILTER] ' --log-level 7
sudo iptables -A BLOCK24 -j REJECT
```

Answer (score 1):

All what you are looking for is available in netfilter (and much more ! ;-) ).

Matching a set of IP ranges to whitelist can be done with ipsets and the match extension “set”:

```
ipset -N whitelist nethash

ipset --add whitelist 1.2.3.4/24
```

Then in netfilter’s iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set whitelist src -j ACCEPT
```

For blocking during 24 hours, you need the match extensions “recent” twice: one to check the incoming rate, and one to remember of blocked sources:

```
iptables -N BLOCK24
iptables -A BLOCK24 -m recent --name blocked --set

iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name beforeblock --rcheck --seconds 1 --hitcount 1 -j BLOCK24
```

This will match if two packets in one second. And now to block sources just match against the “blocked” recent list. This rule of course should be among the first of your iptables rules.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name blocked --recheck --seconds 86400 -j DROP
```

Needed doc is here: [iptables extensions](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) and [ipsets](http://ipset.netfilter.org/ipset.man.html). Of course, can add `-p tcp --dport 80` if these rules should apply only to http.